# Adding columns to Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding columns to datagrid and displaying in my application

```
// Create Datagrid
Mytable = new DataTable("My Table");

// Add Columns
Mytable.Columns.Add(My_Localization.Cultures.Resources.UserId);
Mytable.Columns.Add(My_Localization.Cultures.Resources.Name);

// Fill data
DataRow dr = Mytable.NewRow();
dr[0] = UserId;
dr[1] = Name;

// Add itemsource
DetailsDlg.ItemsSource = Mytable.AsDataView();
```

Now is it possible to change the columns names when my localization languages changes on the fly? Since columns are added in the code, I am not able to change the column headers. If I put the columns in wpf, then I am not able to add the data before assigning the itemsource. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are binding your datagrid from your code behind and you are not using MVVM.

You can always change your desire column in your code behind, like this:

```
DetailsDlg.Columns[0].Header = "New column name";
```

Comment: Is there anyway to use columns from wpf instead of creating them in the code? But then I face a problem of populating the columns

Comment: You mean you want to change the column names from xaml? Yes you can, but those are fixed column headers. Once the program starts you can just change the names from your code behind.